# Sum multi keys depends on total number

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, dataset

## Sum multi keys depend on total number.

**i.e:**
**i have an object of big list or dataset of json file.**

```
var obj = [
  { 'itemz': 'tomato', 'value': 5 },
  { 'itemz': 'potatos', 'value': 3 },
  { 'itemz': 'banana', 'value': 7 },
  { 'itemz': 'orange', 'value': 6 },
  { 'itemz': 'apple', 'value': 4 },
  { 'itemz': 'cherries', 'value': 5 },
  { 'itemz': 'watermelon', 'value': 9 },
  { 'itemz': 'orange', 'value': 8 }
];
var total = prompt("Put the number:");  // i choose 9
```

**i want to get all result itemz that sum of 9:**
**in our example the result will be:**

**items is:**

```
watermelon  //sum=9      
orange, potatos //6+3=9  
apple, tomato   //4+5=9  
apple, cherries //4+5=9
```

- itemz properties is Unique, so there is no duplicate.
- values is not Unique.
- i choose small numbers to count fast and to get my point.
- if can make radio to choose for search by one itemz or two, or three maximium.
- result must be not duplicate i.e: "potatos, potatos, potatos".
- supports utf-8.

Comment: I believe this is a well-known hard problem, perhaps have a read through this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem. There are ways to approach integer solutions using dynamic programming but with non-unique values, I'm just not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something Like this:

```
function subsetSum(numbers, target, partial) {
  var s, n, remaining;
 partial = partial || [];
 s=0;
 for(var j=0;j<partial.length;j++){
    s=parseInt(partial[j].value)+ s;
  }

  // check if the partial sum is equals to target

  if (s === target) {
   console.log("combination is");
   var result="";
    partial.forEach(function(i){result=result+i.itemz+",";})
    console.log(result);
  }


  if (s >= target) {
    return;  // if we reach the number why bother to continue
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    n = numbers[i];
    remaining = numbers.slice(i + 1);
    subsetSum(remaining, target, partial.concat([n]));
  }
}
var obj = [
  { 'itemz': 'tomato', 'value': 5 },
  { 'itemz': 'potatos', 'value': 3 },
  { 'itemz': 'banana', 'value': 7 },
  { 'itemz': 'orange', 'value': 6 },
  { 'itemz': 'apple', 'value': 4 },
  { 'itemz': 'cherries', 'value': 5 },
  { 'itemz': 'watermelon', 'value': 9 }
];
subsetSum(obj,24);
```

Comment: **thank you guys you did good job, but i don`t clear my point.**

**i want every result in new line, i.e:**
<pre>
    watermelon    
    orange, potatos
    apple, tomato 
    apple, cherries
</pre>
**not every array in new line like:**
<pre>
    watermelon    
    orange
    potatos
    apple
    tomato 
    apple
    cherries </pre>

also values is not 1 to 9 only, it`s only example for big numbers.

Comment: **thank you guys you did good job, but i don`t clear my point.**

**i want every result in new line, i.e:**
> watermelon    
 > orange, potatos
 > apple, tomato 
 > apple, cherries

**not every array in new line like:**

  > watermelon    
  > orange
  > potatos
  > apple
  > tomato 
  > apple
  > cherries

also values is not 1 to 9 only, it`s only example for big numbers.

Comment: hi @Roli-Agrawal the code is work fine and will be better to make every result in new line separate by comma as in my example i.e: watermelon\n orange, potatos\n apple, tomato ...etc. also i try console.log at browser with http request but i missed up. also my dataset is big and will better to use external json file.

Comment: your code is amazing @Roli-Agrawal and Exceeded expectations. it can count more than two arrays so can i limited by four maximium arrays. cos i have big list and i wish to use [externaljson](https://api.myjson.com/bins/3rsnv)
also results print only in my terminal how to print result inside browser by http from nodejs. thankyou for supporting me.

Comment: i try to add this code with angularjs but missed up please check full code http://textuploader.com/53vfz

Comment: U only added partial code. Process should be.
1)call http service for data.
2)on success of it pass that data in mention function.
3)return result.

Comment: hi @Roli-Agrawal i try it this but i missid up many times, i can`t fix it http://textuploader.com/53n6y

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = [{
  'itemz': 'tomato',
  'value': 5
}, {
  'itemz': 'potatos',
  'value': 3
}, {
  'itemz': 'banana',
  'value': 7
}, {
  'itemz': 'orange',
  'value': 6
}, {
  'itemz': 'apple',
  'value': 4
}, {
  'itemz': 'cherries',
  'value': 5
}, {
  'itemz': 'watermelon',
  'value': 9
}, {
  'itemz': 'orange',
  'value': 8
}];

var res = obj.filter(function(d) {
  if (d.value == 9) {
    return d;
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
    if (obj[i].value + obj[j].value == 9) {
      res.push(obj[i]);
      res.push(obj[j]);
    }
  }
}

function getUniqueElements(arr) {

  var obj = {};
  var objArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj[arr[i]['value']] = arr[i];
  }
  for (var prop in obj) {
    objArray.push(obj[prop]);

  }
  return objArray;
}
var result = getUniqueElements(res);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: hello @ozil i try your nice code in http request and get this result https://s32.postimg.org/xo9jlzhit/f95.png , this result of screenshot by sum=95, for big list can`t define which arrays equal 95 total. so better to but result every line. and how to use external json will be better for big lists.